# Custom Control Textbox Autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

Good day,

I have a problem with autocomplete on a textbox. I have a custom control:

`public partial class CustomTextBox : UserControl`

Then in this control I add a textbox:

```
public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

        textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = aclist;

        textBox.Multiline = false;

        textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        this.Controls.Add(textBox);

    }
```

Now if I add the textbox in a form and set an AutoCompleteStringCollection to my control's property that I use for the custom autocomplete list, the autocomplete for the textbox will not work at runtime.

But if I add a test AutoCompleteStringCollection in the same place I created the control it works:

```
public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

        textBox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        textBox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;

        AutoCompleteStringCollection list = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        list.Add("Test");

        textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = list;

        textBox.Multiline = false;

        textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

        this.Controls.Add(textBox);

    }
```

Not sure if I'm missing anything. If you need more code to help answer the question please let me know.

I'm using windows forms. Any help will be appreciated.

P.S The reason I don't inherit from a TextBox is because I can't change the textbox height without changing the font size or changing it to a multiline textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem if anyone was curious. Where I assign the autocompletecustomsource in the custom textbox, if I take that out of the public CustomTextBox() { ... } and punt it in, for example the method where I paint the control, it works perfectly. Just under InitializeComponent() the list still shows as empty but only at the paint method it is assigned the values

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
MyCollection(TextBox, "ColumnName", "TableName");

public static AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection(TextBox txt, string ColumnName, string TableName)
{
using (SqlConnection CON = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
        {
            SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT " + ColumnName + " FROM " + TableName + "", CON);
            CON.Open();
            SqlDataReader Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader();
            AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            while (Reader.Read())
            {
                MyCollection.Add(Reader.GetString(0)).ToString();
            }
            CON.Close();
            return txt.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
        }
    }
```

Comment: ... Why would he connect to SQL?